# Find nearest neighbour in a more pythonic way

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor

A is a point, and P is a list of points.
I want to find which point P[i] is the closest to A, i.e. I want to find `P[i_0]` with:

```
i_0 = argmin_i || A - P[i]||^2
```

I do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

# P is a list of 4 points
P = [np.array([-1, 0, 7, 3]), np.array([5, -2, 8, 1]), np.array([0, 2, -3, 4]), np.array([-9, 11, 3, 4])]
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
distance = 1000000000     # better would be : +infinity
closest = None

for p in P:
  delta = sum((p - A)**2)
  if delta < distance:
    distance = delta
    closest = p

print closest    # the closest point to A among all the points in P
```

**It works, but how to do this in a shorter/more Pythonic way?**

**More generally in Python** (and even without using Numpy), **how to find k_0 such that `D[k_0] = min D[k]`?** i.e. `k_0 = argmin_k D[k]`

Comment: Do you have SciPy? [A data structure specifically designed for nearest-neighbor lookup would probably perform better than any array-based solution.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)

Comment: @user2357112 I know that many modules implement nearest-neighbour lookup, but for this example, I would like to code it myself (with no performance optimization, but just shorter code). My question is more how to implement `argmin` nicely in Python.

Comment: More Pythonic != shorter code.

Comment: @user2357112 : In this particular example it is `==`, see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34116108/1422096).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more Pythonic way of implementing the same algorithm you're using is to replace your loop with a call to `min` with a `key` function:

```
closest = min(P, key=lambda p: sum((p - A)**2))
```

Note that I'm using `**` for exponentiation (`^` is the binary-xor operator in Python).

Comment: Great! I didn't know this min/key pattern!

Comment: you can see your code in action here: [Simple (working) handwritten digit recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116526/simple-working-handwritten-digit-recognition-how-to-improve-it)!

Answer (score 2):

A fully vectorized approach in numpy. Similar to the one of @MikeMüller, but using [numpy's broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to avoid lambda functions.

With the example data:

```
>>> P = [np.array([-1, 0, 7, 3]), np.array([5, -2, 8, 1]), np.array([0, 2, -3, 4]), np.array([-9, 11, 3, 4])]
>>> A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

And making `P` a 2D numpy array:

```
>>> P = np.asarray(P)
>>> P
array([[-1,  0,  7,  3],
       [ 5, -2,  8,  1],
       [ 0,  2, -3,  4],
       [-9, 11,  3,  4]])
```

It can be computed in one line using numpy:

```
>>> P[np.argmin(np.sum((P - A)**2, axis=1))]
```

Note that `P - A`, with `P.shape = (N, 4)` and `A.shape = (4,)` will brooadcast the substraction to all the rows of `P` (`Pi = Pi - A`).

For small `N` (number of rows in `P`), the pythonic approach is probably faster. For large values of `N` this should be significantly faster.

Comment: Very fast method indeed! See comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34116234/1422096).

Answer (score 1):

A NumPy version as one-liner:

```
clostest = P[np.argmin(np.apply_along_axis(lambda p: np.sum((p - A) **2), 1, P))]
```

Comment: You're computing a slightly different value (the smallest sum, squared, rather than the sum *of* squares). The numpy bits are probably useful though.

Comment: @Blckknght Ups, missing a pair of parenthesis. Fixed. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I compared both your solution and [@imaluengo's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34122191/1422096) with P containing 5000 vectors of size 10. When doing 1000 different nearest neighbour search, I takes ~60 seconds with this method, and ~ 0.6sec with @imaluengo's method. It would be interesting to see why `np.apply_along_axis` has such an effect.

Comment: Calling Python functions is slow. 'lambda` is pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of the builtin `min` is the way for this:

```
import math
p1 = [1,2]
plst = [[1,3], [10,10], [5,5]]
res = min(plst, key=lambda x: math.sqrt(pow(p1[0]-x[0], 2) + pow(p1[1]-x[1], 2)))
print res
[1, 3]
```

Note that I just used plain python lists.

Comment: The square root is not necessary, since the point with the smallest distance will also be the point with the smallest distance squared.